# my phone stopped showing contacts or logs.

Tags: contacts, call-history

First there was just a lag. Then it showed nothing but was able to use the search function to find the right contact in the list. Finally nothing works. Have to go to Google Contacts to find my contact list and type the number manually.

Answer (score 1):

Go into settings then apps, go to all apps on the scroll at top of page, go down until you find the phone icon with call and message log beside it, force stop it, then shut down phone for 2 minutes, not precise but I left mine off this long, then restart, all logs should be back, hope it helps